# How to subtract data in different rows

Tags: scripting, subtraction

I have a file that has a single column of numbers. I have to subtract value in row1 from value in row2, row3-row2; row4-row3 , row5-row4 and so on for all the rows . Could anybody help me out with this ?

Comment: Is there any particular scripting environment you were thinking of doing this in?  I.e. perl, python, bash, etc.

Comment: Where are you putting the numbers that are subtracting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple BASH script

```
FILENAME=$1

while read line
do
  if [ -n "$prevLine" ]
  then
    curLine=$line
    echo $(($curLine - $prevLine))
  fi
  prevLine=$line
done < $FILENAME
```

So you would type that into a file called `rowdiff.sh` or something like that.  Then you `chmod u+x rowdiff.sh` to make it executable, then `./rowdiff.sh file_with_numbers.txt`

Comment: Thanks  a lot ! Just what i wanted, matt

Answer (score 0):

Load the file up into OpenOffice Calc (or Excel, if you must), and assuming your data starts in A1, into cell B2 put `=(B1-A1)` and then copy&paste that all of the way down to the bottom of your dataset.